# How to detect the device when clicking the link from the mail

Tags: email, html-email

Our requirement is to send an email to user which will be having our site link. Since site can be opened in mobile as well, when user clicks the link from the email it should be redirected to mobile application site if the device is mobile or else desktop site.

Currently we are Using C# to send email. Since Javascript is not supported in HTML body of email, We are looking for some other approach. Can anyone please suggest, how to detect the device and redirect to the link from email appropriately.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually this kind of detection is being done on the other side - while opening the same URL on different devices and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything in the email - Instead use media queries in your website to adjust the result to the screen size. You can either have a responsive site, or use javascript on your main site to reroute them to the mobile version of your website if needed.

There is no real way to do this in email. Technically you could put media queries in your email to show or hide one link or another, but media queries are not 100% supported in email, so you are better off using them on your website.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We decided to give both the links in the mail and let user decide which one he wants to choose.